# Two dependency versions of newtonsoft.json

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-config

I have a project where i need to have two different versions of newtonsoft.json. I tried to use the codeBase like this:

```
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
          <codeBase version="10.0.0.0" href="dll\newtonsoft\10.0.3\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"/>
          <codeBase version="12.0.0.0" href="dll\newtonsoft\12.0.1\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
```

But now i'm getting the "Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly." exception.

I'm not sure about what version should be in the projects References, VS auto install a version in this. Hope someone can help me on the way on this one.

Comment: Well, just remove one of them, depending on what you need.

Comment: Like i said i need both of them, 10.0.3 for umbraco, and 12.0.1 for payment nuget

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is in fact remove one of them, likely the older one. However if you remove that, umbraco would obviously stop working because it expects it to be there, right? The solution is to add a binding redirect to your web.config [as specified here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/assemblybinding-element-for-runtime).  Use a range for the oldVersion attribute so that anything trying to bind to version 0.0.0.0 through 12.0.1 will use the 12.0.1 that is referenced.

Note that this isn't guaranteed to work for every reference because if there have been breaking changes between 10 and 12.0.1 you'll be in trouble, but ideally that will get caught at compile time instead of runtime (if your own code is directly referencing it). If it's not your own code (because there won't be errors until runtime), you need to make sure it works as expected at runtime.

Comment: If i understand you correct, something like this should work? https://codeshare.io/2jYKQM

Comment: That should work as well as long as you modify the oldVersion's end range to be 10.0.3.0 and for the codebase as well, instead of 10.0.0.0. To keep it simpler and only use the one reference (if both things using it will work with it), this is the way to go: https://codeshare.io/Gq6kvj.  

Although, having the unaccounted for gap between version 10.0.3 and 11.0.0.0 would cause an issue if something were to be trying to find 10.0.6, for example.

Comment: Okay, now i got in my References one Newtonsoft.Json Version 10.0.0.0 <--- I can't install a newer that will cause my umbraco to update to umbraco 8, and i don't want that. I changed the codebase to: https://codeshare.io/2jYKQM ... Now it gives me a:  Found conflicts between different versions of "Newtonsoft.Json" that could not be resolved. Error, i tried to delete bin, clean and rebuild